# python function call in other function

Tags: python

so my question is that in my code actually on consists of two python module on the main and other the sub. In sub there is a function which I need to stop the working and return the control back to the next line of the main module. How can it be done. I tried exit() but it stops the execution.
just for example

#module 1 -- ex2

```
import ex1
def add():

    print('before calling ex1')
    ex1.sub()
    print('after calling ex1')

add()
```

#module 2 -- ex1

```
def sub():
    print('inside sub')
    error()
    print('after error call')

def error():
    print('inside error')
    return  #in place of this
```

so I want is that when my code enters the `error` function it will print the statement and the module 2 ends execution and the control will flow to the `print('after calling ex1')` this statement in module 1. Please help guys

note: please do not use multiple returns as example:

#module 2 -- ex1

```
def sub():
    print('inside sub')
    error()
    return  # Please do not use
    print('after error call')

def error():
    print('inside error')
    return  #in place of this
```

I need the output to be like ---

```
before calling ex1
inside sub
inside error
after calling ex1
```

Comment: Use exceptions and `try/except`

Comment: Modules don't implement control flow, only functions do. A module is just a collection of functions/variables and a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) is designed for, with the `raise` statement and the `try .. except` construct in Python:

```
#module 1 -- ex2

import ex1
def add():

    print('before calling ex1')
    try:
        ex1.sub()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print('An error occurred while calling ex1.sub:', str(e))
        # or just a pass statement if you do not want anything done about the error
    print('after calling ex1')

add()

#module 2 -- ex1
def sub():
    print('inside sub')
    error()
    print('after error call')

def error():
    print('inside error')
    raise RuntimeError('some error')
```

Comment: This will technically print that an error occurred too, so perhaps you should replace that line with `pass`

Comment: @Bonfire Sure, added a note then.

Answer (score 0):

Your error function must be a function that returns a value. True or False

```
def error():
    print('inside error')
    return True 
    # or return False

def sub():
    print('inside sub')
    if(error()):
        return
    print('after error call')
```